# SwiftUI refresh the app when user change the location setting in device setting option

Tags: swift, swiftui

My requirement is when the location is disabled, In UI there is a feature "Enabled Location" when the user clicks Enabled location, it will go to setting screen. That is fine working. After changing the setting, and user comes back to app, it should refresh it. This is not working. Not refreshing the app again

My code :

```
struct MainView: View {

 //MARK:- ObservedObject variable
  @ObservedObject private var inStoreVM = InStoreViewModal()
  @ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()

  //MARK: Location coordinate
  var userLatitude: String {
      return "\(locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0)"
  }

  var userLongitude: String {
      return "\(locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0)"
   }

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack { 
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                HomeView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image("home").renderingMode(.template)
                        Text("Home")
                          
                    }.tag(0)


                ExploreView(inStoreVM: inStoreVM)
                    .tabItem {
                        Image("search").renderingMode(.template)
                        Text("Explore")
                          
                    }.tag(1)
                    .onAppear() {
                        print("----onAppear-----TAB")
                    }
                    .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)) { _ in
                        print("----Moving back to the foreground!")
                        locationManager.enableMyAlwaysFeatures()
                    }


    }}}
```

This is my location manager class

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    func registerForLocationUpdates() {

        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {

            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    @Published var locationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus? {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }

    @Published var lastLocation: CLLocation? {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }

    var statusString: String {
        guard let status = locationStatus else {
            return "unknown"
        }

        switch status {
            case .notDetermined: return "notDetermined"
            case .authorizedWhenInUse: return "authorizedWhenInUse"
            case .authorizedAlways: return "authorizedAlways"
            case .restricted: return "restricted"
            case .denied: return "denied"
            default: return "unknown"
        }
    }
}

    extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print(locations)
        guard let location = locations.first else { return }
        lastLocation = location
        self.lastLocation = location
        print(#function, location)

        print("location = \(location.coordinate.latitude) \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        enableMyAlwaysFeatures()
        self.locationStatus = status
        print(#function, statusString)
    }

    func enableMyAlwaysFeatures() {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }

}
```

Any idea, how can I refresh/reload the app, when the user comes from setting screen
I appreciate any advice or help.

Comment: `didSet` doesn't work on `@Published` properties

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, property observers `didSet` and `willSet` don't "work" on `@Published`, since you are simply observing changes to the `Published<...>` object defining the property wrapper, not the wrappedValue `...` itself.

There are two possible approaches.

### First

You can use `Combine` to subscribe to changes of your `@Published` properties.

Example:

```
private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

init() {
   $locationStatus
       .sink { _ in objectWillChange.send() }
       .store(in: &cancellables)

   $lastLocation
       .sink { _ in objectWillChange.send() }
       .store(in: &cancellables)
}
```

This would be equivalent to `willSet`.

Don't forget to import `Combine`.

### Second

You call `objectWillChange.send()` manually right after you change the properties.

For example in your `locationManager(_ , didChangeAuthorization)`:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    enableMyAlwaysFeatures()
    self.locationStatus = status
    self.objectWillChange.send() // <- Here
    print(#function, statusString)
}
```